# MySQL query to list how many times each user appears in several tables

Tags: mysql, list, join, ranking

I'm remaking my question to be more clear.
I have several (5 to be exact) tables where a user could appear only one time. I want to list how many times each user appears.

EXAMPLE:

```
**employess table** 
email | cn | more columns.. user@gr.com | name | etc

**intranet table** 
email | data1 | more columns.. user@gr.com | something | etc
user1@gr.com | something | etc
user2@gr.com | something | etc

**sap table** 
email | data1 | more columns.. 
user@gr.com | something | etc
user1@gr.com | something | etc
user2@gr.com | something | etc

**solman table** 
email | data1 | more columns.. 
user@gr.com | something | etc
user1@gr.com | something | etc
user2@gr.com | something | etc

**orfeo table** 
email | data1 | more columns.. 
user@gr.com | something | etc
user3@gr.com | something | etc

**saul table** 
email | data1 | more columns.. 
user@gr.com | something | etc
user3@gr.com | something | etc

**EXPECTED RESULT**

   email      | Name        | Total
user@gr.com   | name user   | 5  (this is the only user in all the 5 tables)   
user1@gr.com  | name user1  | 3
user2@gr.com  | name user2  | 3  
user3@gr.com  | name user2  | 2
```

I tried a left join but it only returns me one record.. .not a list... What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: "What I´m doing wrong?" So...how do you think we can help you without a query???

Answer (score 0):

This type of query needs to be done with a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT b.email, b.name, count(*)
from 
(
SELECT email from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT email from table2
UNION ALL
SELECT email from table3
UNION ALL
SELECT email from table4
UNION ALL
SELECT email from table5
) as a inner join employess b on a.email = b.email
GROUP BY b.email, b.name
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful!! Smart approach! Thanks! The only thing is not counting right, let´s keep triying.

Comment: What user does it fail? Can you post some data and the result the query produces? SQLFiddle would be helpful